# Transform an upper triangular matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If I have an upper triangular matrix on MATLAB LIKE

```
A =

    1 2 3 4
    0 5 6 7
    0 0 8 9
    0 0 0 1
```

How would you convert it to:

```
a =
    1 2 3 4
    2 5 6 7
    3 6 8 9
    4 7 9 1
```

(transpose and keep the original upper triangular values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy all elements above diagonal to below diagonal in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516142/how-to-copy-all-elements-above-diagonal-to-below-diagonal-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a = A + triu(A, 1)'` does what you want (assuming real matrices or you want a Hermitian matrix for complex values).

Comment: well, the A matrix has only real values

Comment: @darkcminor: Then the answer will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that if you are working with complex numbers and want a transposition of the matrix **without** complex conjugating the values you can use `.'` operator instead of `'`.