# How to copy all elements above diagonal to below diagonal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to copy all elements above diagonal (not on diagonal) to below diagonal without using any loop or with minimum cost. So, after copying the matrix will become a symmetric matrix:
i.e. for all `i`,`j`: `A(i,j)=A(j,i)`.

Thanks.

Comment: @EitanT indeed the questions are very similar, but not duplicate as the case in the other question is with a matrix that has zeros below the diagonal **unlike** this question. Therefore, I believe this question is more general and should be kept open.

Comment: @Shai This fact has indeed crossed my mind. Then again, there's always a certain degree of dissimilarity between duplicates that should be taken into account. The OP is always  expected to do a bit of exploration (within reasonable bounds) by himself/herself to some extent.

Comment: @EitanT in that case I would vote to close the other question as duplicate...

Comment: @Shai Wouldn't marking an *older* question retroactively as a duplicate of a newer one be a bit ridiculous?

Answer (score 7):

Use `triu` command:

```
>> symMat = triu( A, 0 ) + triu( A, 1 ).';
```

This command will leave the diagonal of `A` unchanged.